# Cambiar tamaño grafico de barras chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Estoy trabajando con chartjs para crear un gráfico de barra y no logro dar con alguna opción que me permita modificar el grueso de las barras mostradas, ya que cuando hay pocos datos estas se ven demasiado gruesas, caso contrario cuando hay mas datos estas se ven bien, me sería de gran utilizad si alguien pudiera ayudarme o decirme si eso es posible
este es mi código:

const barsChartOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'bar'>>(() => ({
indexAxis: 'y',
scales: {
x: {
title: {
display: true,
text: 'Devoluciones de Pallets',

```
              font: {
                family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
                size: 10,
                weight: 'bold',
                lineHeight: 1.2,
              },
              padding: { top: 15, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 11 },
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          y: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Proveedor',

              font: {
                family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
                size: 10,
                weight: 'bold',
                lineHeight: 1.2,
              },
              padding: { top: 15, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 11 },
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            font: {
              size: 9,
            },
          },
        },
        
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
      }));
      const dataSet = devolucionesProveedorUseCase.mapDataset(
        this.devolucionesProvedoresGetter as TDevolucionesProveedorDTO[],
      );
      const dataValues = computed<ChartData<'bar'>>(() => ({
        labels: dataSet.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: dataSet.datasets,
            backgroundColor: [
              '#1d864a',
              '#fcc832',
              '#347fab',
              '#ab6034',
              '#7834ab',
              '#4b75e3',
              '#bef539',
              '#769b81',
            ],         
            // barThickness: UNIT_REM,
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 1,
          },
        ],
      }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar el grueso de las barras en tu gráfico de barras en Chart.js, puedes agregar la opción barThickness o barPercentage en la configuración del gráfico. La opción barThickness toma un valor numérico que representa el ancho de cada barra en pixels, mientras que barPercentage toma un valor numérico entre 0 y 1 que representa el porcentaje del ancho del gráfico que debe ocupar cada barra.

Por ejemplo, para establecer el ancho de las barras en 20 pixels, podrías agregar la siguiente línea de código en la configuración del gráfico:

```
const barsChartOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'bar'>>(() => ({
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
        x: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Devoluciones de Pallets'
            }
        },
        y: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Número de Pallets'
            }
        }
    },
    barThickness: 20 // establece el ancho de las barras en 20 px
}));
```

Si, en cambio, quieres establecer el ancho de las barras al 50% del ancho del gráfico, podrías agregar la siguiente línea de código en la configuración del gráfico:

```
const barsChartOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'bar'>>(() => ({
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
        x: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Devoluciones de Pallets'
            }
        },
        y: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Número de Pallets'
            }
        }
    },
    barPercentage: 0.5 // establece el ancho de las barras al 50% del ancho del gráfico
}));
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar tu problema. ¡Buena suerte con tu gráfico!

Comment: Esto me ha servido, muchas gracias!!